# What is the error in code? This seems to run fine in my IDE but doesn't work on online terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, typeerror

I'm trying to solve the leetcode question 8 
[String to integer(atoi)](https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/). But I'm getting a Runtime Error.

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Line 9 in myAtoi (Solution.py)

I understand it's due to a string object getting called but can't seem to figure out what to fix.

```py
class Solution:
    def myAtoi(self, str: str) -> int:
        string = str.strip()
        if string[0]=='-' or string[0]=='+' or string[0].isdigit():
            new = string[0]
            for i in range(1,len(string)):
                if string[i].isdigit():
                    new = new+string[i]
                    if i!=len(string)-1 and (string[i+1]==' ' or string(i+1).isalpha()):
                        break
            if(int(new)>=0):
                if((int(new) & 0x7fffffff)==int(new)):
                    return int(new)
                else:
                    return int(0x7fffffff)
            else:
                if((int(new) & -0x80000000)==int(-0x80000000)):
                    return int(new)
                else:
                    return int(-0x80000000)
```

Can anyone please tell me what to fix here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return anything in the first `if` and you have an error in string calling, you use `()` instead of `[]`, the correct code will be:

```
class Solution:
    def myAtoi(self, str: str) -> int:
        string = str.strip()
        if string[0]=='-' or string[0]=='+' or string[0].isdigit():
            new = string[0]
            for i in range(1,len(string)):
                if string[i].isdigit():
                    new = new+string[i]
                    if i!=len(string)-1 and (string[i+1]==' ' or string[i+1].isalpha()):
                        break
            if(int(new)>=0):
                if((int(new) & 0x7fffffff)==int(new)):
                    return int(new)
                else:
                    return int(0x7fffffff)
            else:
                if((int(new) & -0x80000000)==int(-0x80000000)):
                    return int(new)
                else:
                    return int(-0x80000000)
        else:
          return 0

print(Solution().myAtoi("abc"))
print(Solution().myAtoi("ab"))
print(Solution().myAtoi("a"))
print(Solution().myAtoi("abc d e fgh"))
print(Solution().myAtoi("452 abc d e fgh"))
print(Solution().myAtoi("abc d e fgh 452"))
print(Solution().myAtoi("   -42"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's wondering the final answer to this question, it is:

```
class Solution:
    def myAtoi(self, str: str) -> int:
        string = str.strip()
        if not string:
            return 0
        if not string.strip("+-"):
            return 0
        if string[0]=='-' or string[0]=='+' or string[0].isdigit():
            new = string[0]
            for i in range(1,len(string)):
                if string[i].isdigit() or string[i]=='.':
                    new = new+string[i]
                    if i!=len(string)-1 and (string[i+1]==' ' or string[i+1].isalpha()):
                        break
                elif string[i]=='-' or string[i]=='+':
                    break
                elif string[i].isalpha():
                    break
                else:
                    return 0
            new2 = new.strip("+-")
            if new2:
                if(int(float(new))>=0):
                    if((int(float(new)) & 0x7fffffff)==int(float(new))):
                        return int(float(new))
                    else:
                        return int(0x7fffffff)
                else:
                    if((int(float(new)) & -0x80000000)==int(-0x80000000)):
                        return int(float(new))
                    else:
                        return int(-0x80000000)
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return 0
```

Is this the optimal solution? No! But is the best I could come up with.

Runtime: 44 ms, faster than 47.19% of Python3 online submissions for String to Integer (atoi).
Memory Usage: 13.9 MB, less than 5.95% of Python3 online submissions for String to Integer (atoi).